# Sort Childobjects by specific value

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-extensions

im currently trying to sort all Childobjects i can get by their validity time.

my current code is not sorting anything:

```
$children = $this->productRepository->findByParent($product->getNumber());
        
        
foreach ($children as $child) {
    //debug::debug($child->getvalidityPeriod());
    $product->addChild($child);
}
```

As allready to see in the debug, $child->getvalidityPeriod() is there to get the needed info as integer. I thought, there must be a way to sort this object array by their validityPeriod, but how do i manage that? Do i need to create a new method and filter it there or can i use something BEFORE the ForEach Loop?

Pseudo like:

```
$children = $this->productRepository->findByParent($product->getNumber());
ObjectSortFunction($children, 'getvalidityPeriod');

...and then for each...
```

Would be awesome if somebody would help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after several tries i have a workaround, that can be used as answer, as well ;)

I wrote this method in my repo:

```
public function findByParentSorted($parentId)
    {
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $query->matching($query->equals('parent', $parentId));
        $query->setOrderings(
            [
                'validity_period' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
            ]
        );

        return $query->execute();
    }
```